# Particle travel time in the double-slit experiment?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

In the double-slit experiment, each bright fringe is the result of waves going through both slits and reaching the screen in phase. In other words the difference between the two paths lengths is an integer multiple of the wavelength. For all the fringes except the central one, one path is shorter than the other. In the single-particle experiment, can we time how long the particle takes to reach the screen? If so, what is the result?

Comment: Probably duplicate, at least there is enough information there to answer my own question. I wish I found it earlier, thanks.